# Unity 3d 4.6b New GUI system doesn't take touch when already a touch event is occurring in 3d scene

Tags: unity, unityscript

I know this is beta version but..

I have a Canvas->Button which works fine when I tap it normally.

I have a joystick in my scene which is drawn by separate camera other than mainCamera.

now, while i am operating joystick without leaving it, if I tap on he Canvas->Button - it does not respond. When I lift finger from joystick and tap on it, it works fine.
Same goes for another Canvas->Toggle control.

It has something to do with the layering or anything else...I'm not sure?

Comment: I suggest you file a bug on the appropriate Unity page.

Comment: I'll do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Using the current version of Unity 4.6 I experienced and resolved a similar issue:

My GUI interaction had become non-responsive and unpredictable whilst performing other actions (Particularly while moving the player with keyboard input `WASD`).   My resolution was disabling "Send Navigation Events" from the Event System that was managing my canvas interactions.

Please find the docs here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem-sendNavigationEvents.html

Coming from web, to me this felt like a weird "focus" issue. and setting that "Send Navigation Events" to false resolved everything.